# Is renaming a XSD/WSDL type backward compatible in WS?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl, schema-design

I posted another question about same thing with different approach: 
[extending type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479469/is-modifying-existing-xsd-type-by-extending-it-from-exact-same-type-backward-com).

My problem is basically that I made stupid choice with type naming in XSD and question is what happens if I change a type name in schema? The XML my new client would send to old customer created Web Service would be identical, but can it still cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, renaming an XSD type is backward compatible<sup>1</sup>.  All of the same XML documents that were valid before the renaming will be valid after the renaming.  In fact, it's better than backward compatible because *exactly* the same set of XML documents that were valid before the change will be valid after the change.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Assuming that clients have no direct dependencies against the type names themselves such as via JAXB bindings or `xsi:type` use in XML doc instances. [Thanks to [Petru Gardea.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886533/petru-gardea)]</sub>

Comment: My question title was stupid. As I say in question I knew that XML in messages would be exactly the same so in that sense it's BW-compatible. I was kind of trying to ask is there something more to it. Some validation thing or something i can't think of.

Comment: It's possible that there could be implications if your clients consume your XSD for use in other tools such as JAXB, but that'd be much less important than keeping the changes compatible at the XML/XSD validation level.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in total control of client, but not service. I made the XSD+WSDL, but not the Service. Or Services because already currently there is 2 customer implementations.